# Reading a file from a URL in reverse order in JAVA

Tags: java, file, url, inputstream, urlconnection

I have a server at remote location and I can access logs that are placed on my server using a URL and authentication. The log file that I am trying to access is huge (200 MB - 2 GB). The lines in my server log that I am interested in are present at the end of this file. Below is the method I am using to fetch those last lines.

```
public static void readFileFromURL(SLSearch slSearch)
{
    String currentLine = "";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try
    {
        String webUrl = slSearch.getDomainURL();
        String name = slSearch.getUserId();
        String password = slSearch.getDailyPassword();

        String authString = name + ":" + password;
        
        byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
        String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);

        URL url = new URL(webUrl);
        //URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
        InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        
        br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        
        while((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            if(currentLine.indexOf("2020-08-27 20:37") > 0)
            {
                System.out.println(currentLine);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(ConnectException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(MalformedURLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

To access latest logs, I am reading complete file. I read about `org.apache.commons.io.input.ReversedLinesFileReader` but then it takes argument as `File` and not `InputStream`. Is there a way I can read a file from URL in reverse order? or I can get `InputStream` in reverse order?

Answer (score 0):

When you open an `InputStream` it makes a call to the underlying system (whether it's opening a file, or downloading something from a URL) which automatically starts reading from the beginning.

In order to read an URL in any order, you have to configure your server to start a download in any place, then use `RandomAccessFile` on the URL to get the file at a particular byte.

See: [Download a file through the Internet with RandomAccessFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030768/download-a-file-through-the-internet-with-randomaccessfile)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try to optimize on the writing end.

Have you tried writing logs twice? (Once to a "Master log" as well as a "Latest log" that gets overwritten every so often)

From looking at the InputStreamReader documentation [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inputstreamreader-class-in-java/), there is no built-in way to start reading at a certain index.

Without some form of pre-reading processing of log files, you'd be unable to start reading a file anywhere but the beginning.